# Mylyn for eclipse is bugging me always asking which repository I want to use

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.6, mylyn

Is there a way to disable this question? Is there a way to set a default repository?

Comment: Do you use a repository?

Comment: Do you use a non-local repository?  When you open a task, what repository is identified in the upper right corner?  "Local"? If you click on that, what type of repository is it?  "Textile"?  I don't know much about this, but I think I had the same problem - I just don't remember what I did to fix it!

Comment: ... and no one else is helping.  Do a Window..Show View..Other..Tasks..Task Repositories.  What do you see under "Tasks"?  I think I had to do something in there.  Also... what are you doing when it bugs you?

Comment: @Ed I'm sorry, it's been a while since I last used Eclipse, and I can't remember the answer for all your questions.

Comment: Can you explain "always asking which repository I want to use."  Is this whenever you try to share a project; or whenever you do a commit?

Comment: @Suroot this happens every time I open Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function to set a default repository in eclipse mylyn. for example, when creating a new task in "task list" view , you always need to choose a repository.

I have created a ER for eclipse, see:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=351648

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a default Repository for each Project:

```
Project->Properties->Task Repository
```